# How do I make the twitter search with the rest API?

Tags: twitter

when I write this
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23baseball&result_type=recent to search for  #baseball but then I get a Bad Authentication data.

How do I add the Authentication to the request? I'm asking how do I make the request? Could someone give me an example of how it would look? If I have a Consumer Key and an Access Token?

Comment: Not as well as the docs can: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth

Comment: I tried looking at that, but I didn't understand how to actually build a request?

Answer (score 0):

The 1.1 API assures that all requests made to Twitter are made with some sort of authentication. To try out the API, use the API console here: https://apigee.com/console/twitter

To simply browse the request, use one of the auth methods in the console and pass in your request with GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=baseball&result_type=recent